# Analytical Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a question on analytical integration.

```
z = y/ps; n = 0.95;
A1 = Integrate[((a (a + z) - r^2)/r)^0.95 - (n z) ((a (a + z) - r^2)/r)^-0.05, r]
```

Answer:

```
    1/(ps (-r + (a (a + y/ps))/r)^0.05) 1. (1. + ( ps r^2)/(-1. a^2 ps -  1. a y))^0.05 (a 
     r^4.16334*10^-17 (20. a ps + 20. y) Hypergeometric2F1[0.025, 0.05, 1.025, (1. ps r^2)/(
     1. a^2 ps + 1. a y)] - 0.904762 r^1. y Hypergeometric2F1[0.05, 0.525, 1.525, (1. ps r^2)/(
     1. a^2 ps + 1. a y)] - 0.487805 ps r^2. Hypergeometric2F1[0.05, 1.025, 2.025, (1. ps r^2)/
    (1. a^2 ps + 1. a y)])
```

I found the answer is cumbersome and if possible I want an answer that I can simplify. Do anyone have an idea on how I can make it simple.

Comment: `FullSimplify[%]` shows that there is no simplification of the solution.

Comment: When trying to simplify you should include any known constraints on the variables. For example are any real, positive, nonnegative, nonpositive, negative, rational, integer, restricted to intervals, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you rationalize the input, it will simplify a little more compared to when not using exact numbers, down from 3 calls to `Hypergeometric2F1` to 2.

As rule of thumb, better to use exact numbers with exact functions.

```
z = y/ps; n = 95/100;
Integrand = ((a(a + z)-r^2)/r)^(95/100) - (n z) ((a (a + z) - r^2)/r)^(-5/100);
A1 = Integrate[Integrand, r];
FullSimplify[A1]
```

gives

[image]

Compare to

```
z = y/ps; n = 0.95;
integrand =((a (a + z) - r^2)/r)^0.95 - (n z) ((a (a + z) - r^2)/r)^-0.05;
A1 = Integrate[integrand, r];
FullSimplify[A1]
```

[image]